# can i use admob without uploading at playstore

Tags: android, google-play, admob

[image]

It appears to be working but im not sure if playstore will require me in the future to link it by uploading the app to their playstore. Can anyone confirm if i can leave it unlinked? Thanks!

Comment: You can. If is linked to Google Play the only thing different is that you will have that icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely use Admob without uploading your app to Google Play. The question is why wouldn't you upload your app to Google Play - it is a very large market that you will be missing out on.

Comment: thank you sir, i have a website called apkbuilder.com it generates app using your website with ads. so its not possible for me to upload the apk once it's generated. thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

In 2024, you can't monetize your app with admob without publishing it on Google Play Store or any other Admob supported app store.

Comment: any policies updated or have you faced this problem, i am planning to add admob to my app and not upload to any appstore

Comment: How am I supposed to test the ad units then?

Answer (score 2):

if you link your app to google play from admob console. then admob will fetch up your apps budle id and other information. Rest will be the same. if one of your application is removed from GP by google in case of ban or suspansion. then it will cause to disable ad-serving to that budle id of the application or if your app gets invalid clicks, ad-serving will also disable by admob to your budle id like com.xxxx.xxxx. Linking your app to google play increase the risks in case something goes wrongly...