# Will my Admob account be banned if I export a flutter app to apk and use it on my phone

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-play, admob

I initially built the application to aab and uploaded it to the play store and the application is still in the review, if I make an apk version and install it on my phone and the phones of my friends, there will be a problem knowing that the application contains ads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27672444/4977439

You can distribute apps around Play Store without being banned. Your account will be disabled only when you violate the Admob [policies](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/10502938?hl=en&ref_topic=2745287). Some important information can be found here: https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6168758?hl=en